# How to use operands on date values

Tags: google-sheets, date-comparison

I have a countdown to the current date using `DATEDIF(TODAY(), *The date im counting to in the future*, "d")`. I was wondering if there was a way to do an `IF()` to check if the current date is > the date I'm checking against. I tried (assume the date I'm checking against is A1) `IF((A1 <= 0), IF((A1 = 0), "Today", "Done"), DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1, "d"))`. This should have 3 outputs; "Done", for in the past, "Today", for toady, or else the date difference. I've never really used sheets / excel in this way before and I cant seem to find where the error is. When I use Error.Type(A1) it returns 8.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=if(A1=today(), "Today", if(A1<today(), "Done", DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1, "d")))
```

and see if that works for you ?

Comment: Ah! It works! Thank you. I'm guessing that its because you have to check each variable independently and only check for the true cases?